# Folder Browser Dialog with Environment

Tags: c#, winforms

I created an app for my dad. It's just a simple dictation program. The thing is when he installed it on his computer it stalled and said the general access denied error.

The first time it gave the error I used `SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog()` then added the usually 'if statement" to make sure the dialog was ok. However the app had an access file denied.

I did the same thing with `Environment.GetFolder` and it installed on his computer to the location and ran fine. However, when I use the `saveFileDialog1` and `openFileDialog1` out of the tool box it does not save or open a txt document.

It works on my laptop and not his. Could this be due to an error in the code vs his computer. Also what is the correct way to use the `Environement.GetFolder` with the `SaveFileDialog`.

I can also post the full code to the program if needed.

```
  private void lblOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Title = "Open File";
        open.Filter = "Text Files (*txt) | *.txt";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(open.FileName));

            txtTextBox.Text = read.ReadToEnd();
            read.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void lblSaveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
        save.Title = "Save File";
        save.Filter = "Text Files (*txt) | *.txt";

        if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(save.FileName));

            write.Write(txtTextBox.Text);
            write.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

This is the `Enviroment` i used on my screen recorder. i when i click save it brings up a dialog box i put in the file name press save and it does nothing. It saves the file but not as i specified. So i am trying to merge the above and below codes. The above code does not grant access however the below does

```
string OutputPath;    

OutputPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos) + @"\\IvanSoft Desktop Recorder" + saveFileDialog1;


private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       string fileName = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        fileName = "Tutorial";       
    }
```

the whole code to the program

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Threading;

namespace AGM_Speech
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public SpeechRecognitionEngine recognizer;
        public Grammar grammar;
        public Thread RecThread;
        public Boolean RecognizerState = true;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void lblAbout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            About about = new About();
            about.Show();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder();
            builder.AppendDictation();


            grammar = new Grammar(builder);
            recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(grammar);
            recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

            recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);

            RecognizerState = true;
            RecThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RecThreadFunction));
            RecThread.Start();
        }

        private void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (!RecognizerState)
                return;

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                txtTextBox.Text += (e.Result.Text.ToLower() + " ");
                txtTextBox.SelectionStart = txtTextBox.Text.Length - 0;
                txtTextBox.SelectionLength = 0;

            });
        }

        public void RecThreadFunction()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    recognizer.RecognizeAsync();
                }
                catch
                {

                }


            }
        }

        private void lblStartSpeech_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RecognizerState = true;

        }

        private void lblStopSpeech_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RecognizerState = false;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            RecThread.Abort();
            RecThread = null;
            grammar = null;
            recognizer.UnloadAllGrammars();
            recognizer.Dispose();


        }

        private void lblOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string open = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));


        }

        private void lblSaveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            save.Title = "Save File";
            save.Filter = "Text Files (*txt) | *.txt";

            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(save.FileName));

                write.Write(txtTextBox.Text);
                write.Dispose();
            }
        }




        private void txtSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtSearch.Clear();
            lblGo_Click(null, null);
        }

        private void txtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                lblGo_Click(null, null);

            }
        }

        private void lblGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = 0;
            String temp = txtTextBox.Text;
            txtTextBox.Text = "";
            txtTextBox.Text = temp;

            while (index <= txtTextBox.Text.LastIndexOf(txtSearch.Text))
            {
                txtTextBox.Find(txtSearch.Text, index, txtTextBox.TextLength, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
                txtTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.YellowGreen;
                index = txtTextBox.Text.IndexOf(txtSearch.Text, index) + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you an admin on your machine....is he an admin on his?  Access denied is a permissions error.

Comment: He is an admin on his machine and I am an admin on mine.

Comment: A Few week back i made my own desktop recorder and i used the `Enviroment.GetFolderPath` and deployed it to another computer and it worked. However i could not change the name of the file. So i was wondering if i did it the same way it would work but when the name of the file is typed in do i have to use a text box or can i just use SaveFileDialog to change the text

Comment: i can get the access my problem is not being able to name the saved file when i use `Environment`

Comment: The Environment.GetFolderPath returns a string so you should be able to use it in the saveFileDialog.  You probably should post that code as I do not see you use it anywhere in the example you provided.

Comment: ok hang on a second, and let me post it

Comment: i added the code of when i used the `Enviroment` before but i want to combine the two

Comment: At the end of line where you are instantiating `OutputPath` you add `+ saveFileDialog1`. Not `+ saveFileDialog1.FileName` or something along those lines.

Comment: I didn't actually downvote but http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/NoExceptionDetails seriously. If you have an exception, you need to capture the entire exception details and add it to your question.  Otherwise people have to guess.

Comment: I didn't get any "rep points up".  And, yes, you need to put every single piece of information from the exception into your question for people to help you.  That is explained fully at the link I provided.  If you read it rather than take everything so effing personal, you would be much closer to getting an answer than you are right now.  But, hey, don't listen to me, I don't know anything, I'm just trying to troll to get my rep points up.

Comment: @Will once again how can give you an exception when there was no exception? once again read the question and comments

Comment: "the general access denied error."

Comment: @Will Yes the general access, if you notice i am talking about files so that should tell you right off that i do"t have access to the MyDocuments through `SaveFileDialog` hence the reason to go with `Environment` the thing is when i do the `Environment` which gives you access to special folders such as My Documents it will let read and write to the directory. Now the question is how to merge `SaveFileDialog` and `Environment` together so i can save the file with a file name.

Comment: The above code does not make much sense. `GetFolderPath` would return a folder and not a file. Obviously, you cannot create a file with the same name as an existing folder. If you want to merge path and file parts, then you use `System.IO.Path.Combine`. The MSDN documentation will explain that. If the user should select a name in a specific folder, then set `InitialDirectory` as the result of `GetFolderPath`possibly combined with something else. **And by the way, it should be very obvious what the problem is by inspecting the file name that is used when the error occurs.**

Comment: By the way, you need to verify that a folder actually exists. As far as I know, GetFolderPath might return non existing folder if someone mess up the computer (like redirecting that stuff to another drive that is not available). On the other hand, once you have the problematic folder name, it should be relatively trivial to validate that name in the file explorer (or in a command line windows). Or you can add some tests in your code to verify that a folder exist. And even if a folder exist, access rights might have been screwed up...

Comment: apparently you are not understanding. I don't know how much more simpler i can put. `SaveFileDialog` does not write/read to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` it only reads/writes to localMachine (my desktop). The `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` writes to Special Folders, that is the reason why its used. So to make it more elementary so you can grasp whats going on because other people knows what i am doing, I want to use something like this `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + SaveFileDialog`

Comment: with that said then when i press the save button it will bring the SaveFileDialog box up and the person can save the file with the permissions to read/write to the Special Folders (My Documents).. If you cant understand that then I am not sorry because i am not explaining it again.

Comment: I always use `System.Properties.Default.Settings` and have the user put in their name an then the file reads and writes that way. In my desktop recorder i use `Enviroment` and sometimes for my personal use i use `SaveFileDialog` I am trying to make this as simple and short as possible without adding all the other code. This is for personal use not commercial.. but if i have to make a personal use as a commercial use then i will just do that and have the extra 50 or so lines of code

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say where you're failing, because there isn't much in the way of try/catch or logging.

Can you use this instead, and paste the stack trace that shows in the Message Box?

```
private string fileOutputLocation { get; set; }

private void lblSaveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool fileSelected = false;
    Try(() =>
    {
      SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
      save.Title = "Save File";
      save.Filter = "Text Files (*txt) | *.txt";
      save.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos), "IvanSoft Desktop Recorder");

      if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         fileOutputLocation = save.FileName;
         fileSelected = true;
      }
   });
   if (fileSelected)
   {
      bool fileSaved = SaveFile();
      MessageBox.Show("File saved successfully: " + fileSaved.ToString());
   }
}

private bool SaveFile()
{
   TryDeleteFile();

   bool fileSaved = false;

   Try(()=>
   {
     File.WriteAllText(fileOutputLocation, txtTextBox.Text);
     fileSaved = true;
   });

   return fileSaved;
}

private void TryDeleteFile()
{
   Try(()=>
   {
      if (File.Exists(fileOutputLocation))
      {
         File.Delete(fileOutputLocation);
      }
   });
}

private void Try(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The following exception was thrown:\r\n{0}\r\n\r\nFile path: {1}", e.ToString(), fileOutputLocation));
    }
}
```

With this, plus the events logged to the Windows Event Viewer (Start>Run>Eventvwr>Security), we should be able to tell you what the problem is.

Lastly, if you're just providing an executable to run, you should check the properties of the file to ensure it's not blocked in Windows.

Comment: what i can do is post the whole code, that has the SaveFileDialog so you can see the whole code of the program its only about 100 lines of code. Also this app is just a small note taking app. My dad does not like the MS Speech because it pauses and he does not like the layout. So the app just omits everything and goes through the app. Its just a basic app. Now the `Environment` part is in my custom desktop screen reader. i built it in win8.1 and deployed it to 10. I can do it that way its just saving the file as what he types. That is my problem. i will put the whole code in the question

Comment: I would still ask you to run this code and provide the details. There isn't enough detail in what you're providing to run this down any further. The code and details I asked for would give us the necessary data. The problem is obviously environmental, but without getting details, we can't help you any more.

Comment: I am having to modify it a little bit because it throws some generic errors like `;` and `(` are expected. and i wont be able to test it until late tonight when i send the download link to my dad. The only other laptop i have to test it on is not here it got sent in to the service shop for a new Mobo. So I will post the results tomorrow.

Comment: Edited to correct some of that. I wrote it freehand, so there may be more.

Comment: Thanks. Any changes you have to make to the code will be important to, so if you end up modifying it, please post that code as well (and the less, the better!).

Comment: i am doing some testing to see which one it is.. I have been tied up doing websites for customers and trying to reach my goal for phase 1 of the IvanSoft Speech Engine.. i will post some info shortly.